# Python sqlalchemy TypeError when trying to iterate through .all() query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, typeerror

I have a python BaseHTTPServer, that returns a list of restaurants via a .all() query. It works fine on the first run, but after an update I get

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.0.2.2', 49927)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 328, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "webserver.py", line 43, in do_GET
    allRestaurants = session.query(Restaurant).all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2703, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2855, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2876, in _execute_and_instances
    close_with_result=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2885, in _get_bind_args
    **kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2867, in _connection_from_session
    conn = self.session.connection(**kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 966, in connection
    execution_options=execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 971, in _connection_for_bind
    engine, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 382, in _connection_for_bind
    self._assert_active()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 276, in _assert_active
    % self._rollback_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 258, in __str__
    details.append("[parameters: %r]" % params_repr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 368, in __repr__
    return self._repr_multi(self.params, typ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 386, in _repr_multi
    for params in multi_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 386, in <genexpr>
    for params in multi_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 412, in _repr_params
    ", ".join(trunc(value) for value in params)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Is the .all() query returning an int Instead of a list? 
Or is this some internal error with one part of sqlalchemy passing another part an int instead of something iterable?
It's way beyond my expertise to debug a library, so I'm just scratching my head.
Please help.
Here is an abbreviated version of my webserver file:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import cgi
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, Restaurant, MenuItem

# Database setup on webserver load instead of pageload
dbpath = 'sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db'
engine = create_engine(dbpath)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = DBSession()
restaurants = session.query(Restaurant)
assert(type(restaurants) != "int")


class webServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        try:

            if self.path.endswith("/restaurants"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                output = ""
                output += "<html><body>"
                assert(type(restaurants) != "int"), "type has changed."

                session.flush()
                allRestaurants = session.query(Restaurant).all()
                for restaurant in allRestaurants:
                    output += "<h1>" + restaurant.name + "</h1>"
                    output += '''<a href="http://localhost:8080/restaurants/''' + repr(restaurant.id) + '''/edit">Edit</a>'''
                    output += '''<a href="http://localhost:8080/restaurants/''' + repr(restaurant.id) + '''/delete">Delete</a>'''


                output += "</body></html>"
                self.wfile.write(output)
                print(output)
                return

            if self.path.endswith("/edit"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                id = int(self.path.split('/')[-2])
                restaurant = restaurants.filter_by(id = id).one()
                output = ""
                output += "<html><body>"
                output += "<h1>" + restaurant.name + "</h1>"
                output += '''<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/restaurants/''' + repr(restaurant.id) + '''/edit'><h2>Please rename the restaurant</h2><input name="message" type="text" ><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>'''
                output += "</body></html>"
                self.wfile.write(output)
                print(output)
                return       

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

    def do_POST(self):
        try:
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(
                self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
                formName = self.headers.getheader('name')
                print(fields)
                print(self.path)
                messagecontent = fields.get('message')
                id = int(self.path.split('/')[-2])
                restaurant = restaurants.get(id)
                restaurant.name = messagecontent
                session.add(restaurant)
                session.commit()
                DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
                session = DBSession()
                assert (restaurants.filter_by(id = id).one().name == messagecontent), "Database update failure"

            output = ""
            output += "<html><body>"
            output += " <h2> Restaurant renamed: </h2>"
            output += "<h1> %s </h1>" % messagecontent[0]
            output += '''<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'><h2>What would you like me to say?</h2><input name="message" type="text" ><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>'''
            output += "</body></html>"
            self.wfile.write(output)
            print(output)
        except:
            pass
```

UPDATE - I added DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine) and session = DBSession() after the database commit and now have a InterfaceError: unprintable InterfaceError object

Comment: Note that `type(restaurants) != "int"` will pretty much always be *True*, since `type()` returns the actual type of the given expression. You should be comparing to `int`, not a string `"int"`. Also include your model definitions in your question.

Comment: Thanks so for that to work correctly it would be 'type(restaurants) != int()' ? @IljaEverilä

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work out the multiple issues I was having!

Importantly, don't try and create one session instance for a webserver, as I did by declaring the session variable outside of the `do_GET`and `do_POST`methods.

This is because the file load created a session -> which worked for the first query -> but the do_POST method then invalidates the session after the `commit()` call. This meant on the second query the session returns an int (I assume this is an error code form sqlalchemy), hence the TypeError.

Secondly, the POST method was returning a list of form field values which I was then trying to assign to a String database field.